# Groovy: sort hash keys by values value

Tags: sorting, hash, groovy

I want to sort a hash of key->value by the values , and get the list of the sorted keys.

This seems to work:

```
groovy> def map = [a:5, b:3, c:6, d:4].sort { a, b -> a.value <=> b.value }.keySet() 
groovy> println map 

[b, d, a, c]
```

but will it always work? 
I don't know if the iterator that builds the keySet() will always iterate them by order.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Short answer*: Yes, the `keySet()` method will always return an *ordered* `java.util.List`.

*Long answer*: That's a bit hard to prove as we have to look at some source code.

Examination starts in `groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods` where the `public static <K, V> Map<K, V> sort(Map<K, V> self, Closure closure)` method returns a `java.util.LinkedHashMap`, which is *ordered*.

The `LinkedHashMap`'s `Set<K> keySet()` method is defined in the `java.util.HashMap` class and returns an `Iterator` by calling the `Iterator<K> newKeyIterator()` method, which is overriden in the `LinkedHashMap` class][4]. It returns a `LinkedHashMap$KeyIterator`, which [defines the `K next()` method that internally calls the `Entry<K,V> nextEntry()` method, which returns an `Entry` that has been defined in the `LinkedHashMap$Entry.after` field.

Finally, one can see in the `LinkedHashMap$Entry.addBefore(Entry<K,V> existingEntry)` method that the `LinkedHashMap$Entry.after` field is set in an *ordered* manner.

---

Oh my ... I had linked each statement I did to the corresponding source code in `groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods`, `java.util.HashMap` and [`java.util.LinkedHashMap`](http://kickjava.com/src/java/util/LinkedHashMap.java.htm), summing up to 10 hyperlinks. Unfortunately, as a newbie at Stackoverflow, I'm just allowed to post one, having to remove most links ... Sorry.